# How to upload sketch in ESP32 with rpi4?

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I bought a doit devkit v1 somedays ago. I have Arduino installed in my raspberry pi(binaries from arduino.cc). I installed the board today and tried to upload a simple code. But it cold not upload the code. It is showing some sort of 'broken pipe' error. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Are you using the following? "DOIT Esp32 DevKit v1": https://docs.zerynth.com/latest/official/board.zerynth.doit_esp32/docs/index.html. For newbies, I would suggest to first try Win10 UART/serial, if you find everything OK, you can move on to Rpi buster UART/serial.

Comment: I vaguely remember that if you use Arduino IDE configured to ESP12/32, then you must use MicroPython. But I am a couple of months out of date. Please correct me otherwise. BTW, I have a couple of ESP32 modules in hand.  I am happy to repeat your situation or share your experience, but NOT on Arduino IDE/MircoPython. I only play with NodeMCU LUA.

Comment: Are you following the RandomNerd? "Getting Started with the ESP32 Development Board": https://randomnerdtutorials.com/getting-started-with-esp32/.

Comment: Or you might like to try also RandomNerd's recommendation uPyCraft IDE: (1) "Install uPyCraft IDE – Windows PC Installation Instructions":
https://randomnerdtutorials.com/install-upycraft-ide-windows-pc-instructions/
"uPython Docs": https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp32/tutorial/intro.html. But it still uPython, so I might only briefly mess with it later, using Win10 PC.

Comment: PS - uPyCraft IDE also runs in Ubuntu 16.04, but might not work with Rpi4B Raspbian buster.

Comment: Try https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions